# ASP.NET: I'm trying to set a label to show an image button but it isn't showing no the page, How do i do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I'm trying to add an image button to a gridview by setting it to a label as per the below code, but it isn't showing on the page. Please could you show me where I'm going wrong?

```
 lbl3.Text = "<asp:ImageButton id=\"SuperSButton\" runat=\"server\" Image src=\"Images/Prop.png\" OnClick=\"superSession_Click\"/>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointed in the right direction by James I got it to work using a different method.

Firstly I added a templatefield to my gridview:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SuperSButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/Prop.png" OnClick="superSession_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then I added this to the code behind:

```
 ImageButton LB1 = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("SuperSButton");
        LB1.Visible = false;

        if (line.SuperSessionFlag)
        {
            if(line.SuperSessionIndicator == "1" || line.ErrorType =="S" )
            {

                LB1.CommandArgument = line.PartNumber;
                LB1.Visible = true;
            }
```

Finally, I added a rowcommand instead of an onclick event to perform the action

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add it like that. Build the image button and the add it to your gridview.

```
var img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "SuperSButton";
img.ImageUrl = "images/Prop.png";
img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(superSession_Click);
img.Width = 48;
img.Height = 38;

//then add it somewhere in your grid
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: I think `OnClick` is a method, you should use `Click` event instead (refer to [ImageButton reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: This hasn't quite worked for me, I wanted to add the button to a column but not for it not always be visible. But it was very useful to point out that the way that I was doing it is wrong. I've got it working now, I'll add my solution.

Comment: Glad you have got it working Andy! I wasnt quite sure where you wanted it on the grid so just put it within a cell on the footer for my example. If you need to set the button to be invisible based on a condition then you will need to loop through the rows collection of the gridview to find the button or better yet use the findcontrol function as you have mentioned in your solution. Once you have found it you can then change any attributes you wish on the button

Comment: @JamesBlackburn That's fair, I hadn't explained the rest of it because I thought I had the rest of it right, Turns out I hadn't! Thanks for your help.